# Java 2D Array manipulation

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to modify the below method:

```
private final static int NUM = 6;

public void fun(int[][] grid) {
    for(int row = 0; row < NUM; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < NUM; col++) {
            if((grid[row][col] % 2) == 0) {
                grid[row][col] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method checks if it's a even number and if so it replaces its value with 0.  Simple.

I now need to modify it so that it directs each cell to simultaneously replace its value with its number of diagonal neighbors that hold a value of 0.

I've thought about this for about an hour and tried many different solutions, most of which resulted in an out of bounds exception.  I'm stumped and don't know how to accomplish this.

If the code is right, using the integers for the grid array below, it will reproduce the numbers shown in the bottom of the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APxSG.png).

[image]

Comment: Well depending on the array index it may be a lesser or greater amount of neighbors.  For example grid[0][0] only has 1 diagonal neighbor.  I had a hard time accounting for that and it resulted in array out of bounds exceptions.  And i'm pretty sure that most of them have 4 diagonal neighbors.  It's only the diagonal neighbors.

Comment: I edited the OP.  Check it out.  Using the array in the top of the picture with the right code would produce the numbers in the bottom of the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the problem, you just need to put if statements, like there can be maximum 4 possible neighbors so check that how many are equal to `0`. But this is not enough you just need to add one more condition in each of the if statements. The condition would be that the neighbor you are trying to check is possible or not.

That is: Total 4 neighbors. If the coordinates of your main cell are x, y then:
1st Diagonal neighbor: `x-1`, `y-1`
2nd Diagonal neighbor: `x-1`, `y+1`
3rd Diagonal neighbor: `x+1`, `y+1`
4th Diagonal neighbor: `x+1`, `y-1`

These are all the 4 diagonal neighbors' coordinates but the last thing you need to check is whether they go out of bonds or not. For example for checking the 1st Diagonal neighbor I would do:

```
if((x-1)>0 && (y-1)>0){
    //and then check here if that block is = `0`
}
```

and for other having say `x+1` or `y+1` you will need to check whether or not they are less than the NUM. Like if I want to check the 3rd Diagonal Neighbor:

```
if((x+1)<NUM && (y+1)<NUM){
    //and then check here if that block is = `0`
}
```

**Update:** `What do you mean by check here if that block is = 0?`

If you want to check that is the diagonal neighboring blocks are equal to `0` or not then you will need to do it in a loop. Here is how:

```
public void fun(int[][] grid) {
    for(int row = 0; row < NUM; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < NUM; col++) {
            if((grid[row][col] % 2) == 0) {
                grid[row][col] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    for(row = 0; row< NUM; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < NUM; col++) {
            int count = 0;

            // To check for the 1st Diagonal Neighbor
            if((row-1)>0 && (col-1)>0){
                if(grid[row-1][col-1]==0){
                    count++;
                }
            }

            //Similarly for 2nd, 3rd and 4th Diagonal Neighbors

            //and then
            grid[row][col]=count;
        }
    }

}
```

**Update 2:**
For say the 3rd diagonal neighbor the code block would be like this:

```
if((row+1)<NUM && (col+1)<NUM){
    if(grid[row+1][col+1]==0){
        count++;
    }
}
```

**Answer**
    final private static int NUM = 6;

```
public void fun(int[][] grid) {
    for(int row = 0; row < NUM; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < NUM; col++) {
            int counter = 0;

            if((row - 1) > 0 && (col - 1) > 0) {
                if(grid[row - 1][col - 1] == 0) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            if((row - 1) > 0 && (col + 1) < NUM) {
                if(grid[row - 1][col + 1] == 0) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            if((row + 1) < NUM && (col - 1) > 0) {
                if(grid[row + 1][col - 1] == 0) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            if((row + 1) < NUM && (col + 1) < NUM) {
                if(grid[row + 1][col + 1] == 0) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            grid[row][col] = counter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying.  Could you write a snippet of code for me to grasp it?

Comment: @NoahMatisoff Check out the last block and then tell me your doubt

Comment: What do you mean by check here if that block is = 0?

Comment: Okay, so for the remaining 3 diagonal neighbors I should copy the block of two if statements and replace the row - 1 && col - 1 with what you put above that?

Comment: Also, this doesn't account for the corners, right?  If row - 1 or col - 1 is not greater than 0 what would happen..?

Comment: @NoahMatisoff What do you mean by doesn't account for the corners? I did not get you.
If row-1 or col-1 is not greater than 0 then it means that that block you are trying to search does not exist. Like if you are searching on block 0,0 row-1 = -1 and col-1 = -1 and -1,-1 block does not exist. So it would not even try to check what is in grid[-1][-1]

Comment: If it's a corner, row - 1 or col - 1 will not be greater than 0.  That means the code will just move on and not account for the corners in the array that have less neighbors.

Comment: Ahhh okay I get it now.  I can't test it until tomorrow but thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @NoahMatisoff It would account for the one's having less neighbors too, because see the if loop checking if `row - 1 or col - 1 will not be greater than 0` ends before checking the new block, so if this is untrue it would not check the value at that block(-1,-`) but it would check whether the other neighbors are there or not and if anyone of the neighbors is present it will for sure check whether the neighbor==0 or not and if it is, it will surely increase the count

Comment: Check my updated OP and make sure I did it properly according to what you're saying, please.

Comment: @NoahMatisoff No it is wrong, you are checking whether everything is greater than 0 or not. But what you really need to check is whether the elements like `row-1` and `col-1` are greater than 0 and in contrast the elements `row+1` and `col+1` are less than `NUM` See the answer in my updated answer